# How to skip a required CRD property for server-side apply with kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'd like to patch an existing [PrometheusRule](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/prometheus-operator-crds-8.0.1/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/charts/crds/crds/crd-prometheusrules.yaml) which has `spec.groups[].rules[].expr` required. The existing rule has an `expr`, however I'd like to omit it from my patch because the existing one is fine and I don't won't to copy and thus have to maintain it in my patch:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  name: kube-prometheus-stack-kubernetes-apps
  namespace: observability
spec:
  groups:
    - name: kubernetes-apps
      rules:
        - alert: KubePodNotReady
          for: "9m"
```

I tried different forms of patches and server-side apply which as far as I understand is the successor of `kubectl patch`, e.g.

```
kubectl apply -f patch-plain.yaml --server-side --field-manager=unique-name --force-conflicts --validate=false
```

Nothing accepts the patch without `expr`. Sticking to the schema in the CRD is imperative for creating new object, however patches can skip the requirements if a value already exists imo, so maybe there's an option or alternative I'm missing.

Sub-optimal workarounds I'm aware of:

1. Patching with indices: `kubectl patch prometheusrule kube-prometheus-stack-kubernetes-apps -n observability --type='json' -p='[ {"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/groups/0/rules/1/for", "value": "10m"} ]'` increases maintenance because one needs to check whether the patch still has the right index after updating the chart installing the initial `PrometheusRule` (with a list of rules).
2. ChatGPT claim, one can use `/spec/groups/name=kubernetes-apps/rules/alert=KubePodNotReady/for`, but that doesn't work and I don't find anything about it.
3. Making the patch a template and then read and insert `expr` before a patch. But that's so not patching.
4. Duplicating the `expr` and maintaining it in the patch. Also sub-optimal.
5. Getting the index in a separate jsonpath query and using the index-based patch which now "safe", but that seems like working against the tool.

I added `--validate=false` to the example above which doesn't fix the problem. I don't consider it a good solution.